# After initial Intellij example, I am unable to build upon the example and view new Functional Components

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea, kotlin-multiplatform, ktor

While I have been successful in being able to run and use the Intellij Example on the Full Stack approach with Ktor and React. I am unable to further develop the test example.

Shortly after completing the tutorial and being able to see the 'Hello from Ktor' and also the green bar that matched the JS side, I was then unable to see beyond just the Ktor side.
Losing all of the visuals from the JS Side.

I have tried also to start again with the already developed Full Stack Project, which also worked until I created a new Functional Component.

I have researched many different ways in order to try and get this to work.
Such as Clearing Cache and using the Private Window in order to see if there is any caching issues - same problem was visible.

...
(Second shot)

Creating from the 'Full Stack Web Application' project template.
I had got everything working, as expected 'Hello from Ktor' and green bar to change name.

When I started the Gradle task 'run' in order to get both the Server and Client side up, I was then able to see just the Ktor line - "Hello from Ktor" and then the rest of the page was empty. Inspecting the page for the HTML there was only the root section, and not a div section as expected.
The JS side was not popping up at all.
Again going through the cache and private windows to check if it is something else - and getting the same result with only the one line displayed.

...

I can only assume that this is either something to do with Intellij and the way that it is set up on my computer or that there is something outside of the kotlin code that is affecting the application. Because it did work sometimes, but nothing consistent and mainly no results have come up recently.

Any other ideas would be quite gladly looked into.

**Ktor and React Application - where I can only see that the Ktor part is working, whereas the JS Side is not working at all anymore. How am I able to get the JS part back to working again, alongside the Ktor Server?**

***Client.kt***

```kotlin
    fun main() {

    // append Welcome
    val container = document.createElement("div")

    document.body!!.appendChild(container)

    val welcome = Welcome.create {
        name = "Kotlin/JS"
    }
    createRoot(container).render(welcome)


    // append Initial
    val container2 = document.createElement("div")
    document.body!!.appendChild(container2)

    val initial = Initial.create {
    //        name = "Kotlin/JS"
    }
    createRoot(container2).render(initial)

    }
```

***Initial.kt*** -- extra FC

```kotlin
val Initial = FC<Props> {

    h1 {
        +"Hello, React+Kotlin/JS!"
        +"Hello, React+Kotlin/JS!"
    }

    button {
        title = "Button Here"
    }

    h2 {
        +"Second Heading Test"
    }

}
```

***Server.kt***

```kotlin
fun HTML.index() {
    head {
        title("Hello from Ktor!")
    }
    body {
        div {
            +"Hello from Ktor"
        }
        div {
            id = "root"
        }
        script(src = "/static/FST.js") {}
    }

}

fun main() {
    embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080, host = "127.0.0.1") {
        routing {
            get("/") {
                call.respondHtml(HttpStatusCode.OK, HTML::index)
            }
            static("/static") {
                resources()
            }
        }
    }.start(wait = true)
}
```

Above code is mostly from the Intellij template.
Only attempting to add a new FC as is 'Initial'.
Still not able to see the rest of the JS part even if the 'Initial' sections are removed.

Comment: Could you please share your project to troubleshoot your problem?

Comment: @AlekseiTirman Hi and thanks. I have added the code into the question. Wasn't sure if it would be a quick and easy thing to mention to me or something that you actually did need the code for :) - Let me know if there is anything else needed.

Comment: It works fine for me. Could you please tell me what is the name of the Javascript file in `<project-path>/build/distributions`? Please check that the correct Javascript file name is specified in `script(src = "/static/FST.js") {}`.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman yes that worked. I played around a bit more and it was due to the change in my settings.gradle.kts - this change renamed the FST to something more appropriate for my project. So effectively when there is a change in the settings file, I would need to update the js file within the code so that it matched properly. Then the generated js file would have the same name as what is configured in the settings and should work as expected.
Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: You can hardcode the name of a generated JS file if you want: 
`val webpackTask = tasks.getByName<KotlinWebpack>(taskName)`

`webpackTask.outputFileName = "some-name.js"`